# Translators in Dubai airport immigration

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dubai, uae, language-barrier

I will be traveling to Dubai and am trying to arrange for my wife to meet me there after I arrive (it's not possible for the both of us to go on the same day).

However, she only speaks Portuguese and some Spanish -- no English at all or any other language. She's afraid about being unable to communicate if the immigration officer needs to ask her the usual questions like purpose of her trip, travel arrangements, availability of funds during her stay, etc.

I'm wondering if there are translators available that speak either Portuguese or Spanish in the airport. Failing that, would she be allowed to use her cell phone and a translation app to speak to the immigration officer?

Comment: Talking with travellers without sharing a common language is a common part of the job of any immigration officer. I have no doubt that the immigration officers in Dubai will be able to provide a translator if they need to talk to your wife.